# routing for adding ips to 2 interfaces from same subnet

Tags: routing, linux-networking

I am trying to add 2 different ips from same subnetmask to two different interfaces. So far it is working fine with the config below. Now I want to add an ip alias as well

My eth0.cfg is:
auto eth0

```
iface eth0 inet static
   address 7.7.7.4
   network 7.7.7.0
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 7.7.7.255
   up ip route add 7.7.7.0/24 dev eth0 src 7.7.7.4 table eth0table
   up ip route add default via 7.7.7.1 dev eth0 table eth0table
   up ip rule add from 7.7.7.4 table eth0table
   up ip route add 7.7.7.0/24 dev eth0 src 7.7.7.4
```

So my question is how do I write it for eth0:1?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
iface eth0 inet static
  ...
  up ip addr add 192.168.10.10/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1
  down ip addr del 192.168.10.10/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1
  up ip route add 192.168.0.10/24 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0:1 metric 20
  down ip route del 192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0:1 metric 20
```

and in your case it will be like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
  address 7.7.7.4
  network 7.7.7.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 7.7.7.255
  up ip route add 7.7.7.0/24 dev eth0 src 7.7.7.4 table eth0table
  up ip route add default via 7.7.7.1 dev eth0 table eth0table
  up ip rule add from 7.7.7.4 table eth0table
  up ip route add 7.7.7.0/24 dev eth0 src 7.7.7.4
  up ip addr add 192.168.10.10/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1
  down ip addr del 192.168.10.10/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1
  up ip route add 192.168.0.10/24 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0:1 metric 20
  down ip route del 192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0:1 metric 20
```

I would also recommend adding `down` rules for your routes to make sure they are removed when interface is taken down.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. So can you please explain about what these do a bit?

Comment: The first `up` stanza creates `eth0:1` sub-interface, the second - adds routing for it. In your case you will need to add your own source routing rules for `eth0:1`.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me a place where I can read about this. I still don't understand what to give in my case. this is what I came up with: http://pastie.org/private/7dl9aw40hhdmhtxx7wh3uw Is this correct? I don't think it is, but still!

Comment: Configuration from the link is wrong. You need to add these lines to the configuration from your question. Essentially you configure all sub-interfaces under `iface eth0 ...`. The reason is that when `eth0` goes up or down its sub-interfaces go with it. I'm updating my answer for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. One more thing though, In your answer, I see you have given ranges for eth0:1. I want to assign it 7.7.7.5, so can I replace those ranges with 7.7.7.5

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong. It didn't solve my problem. This is what I did: http://pastie.org/private/6ivsoo5jgjqthwn8gztwg

Comment: @defiant, the lines I gave you are just an example of how to set up a subinterface with destination based routing. My understanding is that you are looking for source based routing. Essentially, you will need to replicate what you did for eth0 to eth0:1.